# OpenCV Cascade Classifier load error iOS

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, cascade-classifier

Currently I am trying to using an OpenCV Cascade Classifier to detect faces in my iOS app. The problem is that when I go to load the classifier, it fails because the pathname to the "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" isn't correct.

Here is my code:

```
cv::String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
```

void detectFaces(cv::Mat frame){

```
cv::CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
if (face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)){
    printf("Load complete");
}else{
    printf("Load error");
}
std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;

std::vector<cv::Mat> rgbChannels(3);
cv::split(frame, rgbChannels); // Making the frame gray scale
cv::Mat frame_gray = rgbChannels[2];

face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE|CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT, cv::Size(150,150));

if(faces.size()> 0){
    printf("TRUE");
}
```

}

Since this is an iOS project I don't know how to find the path of the required xml file in the framework. What is the proper way to load a Cascade Classifier into an iOS project? Or, what is the correct way to include the right filename so that it sees it properly?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with the full path?

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this with C++? I can't find the file's full path because I don't have OpenCV installed on my computer. Have been testing it with an iPhone so I haven't needed it.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, you need to locate the file path within the app bunnle. Something like this:

```
// get main app bundle
NSBundle * appBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];

// constant file name
NSString * cascadeName = @"haarcascade_frontalface_alt";
NSString * cascadeType = @"xml";

// get file path in bundle
NSString * cascadePathInBundle = [appBundle pathForResource: cascadeName ofType: cascadeType];

// convert NSString to std::string
std::string cascadePath([cascadePathInBundle UTF8String]);

// load cascade
if (face_cascade.load(cascadePath)){
    printf("Load complete");
}else{
    printf("Load error");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Quang. Currently my code is in just regular C++ that I am including within my OpenCV wrapper. So therefore I can't use objective-c code within my file. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You can mix C++ and Objective-C++ as long as you name your file `.mm` (or specify the source code type as Objective-C++).